# Passing files to SAGE on Mac OS X

Tags: texlive, sagetex

- System: Mac OS X 10.9.2
- Sage Version 6.1.1, Release Date: 2014-02-04
- TexLive 2013 installation

I'm trying to pass a file generated by LaTex (sagetex.sty) that is in SAGE format to my local installation of SAGE.

```
$ sage test_sagetex_installation.sagetex.sage
dyld: Symbol not found: _rl_executing_keyseq
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
Expected in: /Applications/sage/local/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
in /usr/local/bin/bash
```

I have confirmed that I can pass commands directly to SAGE through the command line:

```
$ sage -c 'print factor(35)’
5 * 7
```

It seems like this error has to do specifically with passing a file to sage. I'm a little lost about how to debug this error.

Comment: Have you checked that your `sage` package is the one coming from your Sage distribution rather than your TeXLive distribution?

Comment: Yes. I don't believe that my TexLive dist even has a sage package, since sagetex doesn't appear in the package manager list. And it seems like I should be able to write a .sage file and pass it to SAGE just like I do with the -c option. So not only am I having trouble with the LaTex-generated SAGE file, but I can't pass any file into the SAGE program from the command line.

Comment: The errors may be unrelated, but I would start by trying to get a basic `.sage` file running. If you can't figure out how to do that, you might try asking on the [Sage support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support). There's also a non-StackExchange [Sage Q&A site](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) you can browse, but "questions from new users are temporarily disabled."

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error today after installing Bash via homebrew, as I wanted to use the newer version that OSX doesn't ship with. I simply ran `brew uninstall bash`, and changed my default shell back to the old version of Bash that comes with OSX (3.2, I believe). After doing this, I was again able to run my old Sage files as in your example. If you too are using the newer version of Bash, you could either uninstall it like I did, or try changing your shell to the old version to see if that rectifies the problem. While I do not know a permanent solution, I am hoping this at least helps to pinpoint the issue.